# Avoiding duplication Web Spotify API

Tags: spotify

I am trying to make a script that synchronise playlists from my website and Spotify with Spotify Web API.

However, I have a problem to avoid duplication: When a user has already created a synchronized playlist and want to update it, I want to make a system that checks the music already imported in Spotify and not add them again.

Is there a solution for this? I try with the API by getting every music to test each time, but it is very complicated to have to check the entire playlist for each title that is important.

I thought to suppress the last playlist and created a new one with all music, is this a good idea or not?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question here. Is it possible that you could rephrase it with some examples?

Comment: Yes you can suppress a playlist and create new one, all of this by name. It does work here on my side. Make sure that you wait between the events, because the API (at least the old libspotify one) allows for duplicate playlist names, and may risk believing that your playlist with a given name exists only once or not anymore when that is actually not the case online.